# Cocos2d-x fails to build android APK

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've created a cocos2d-x (3.14.1 and 3.15.1) project, I've modified template slightly and added new sprite. This compiles fine in VS and application seems to run. I wanted to build android apk so I've tried these two commands (with api level android-21 and 24, also using android-ndk-r15):

```
cocos deploy -p android
cocos deploy -p android --android-studio
```

It seems to start building correctly but eventually it fails with these errors:

```
    D:/coco2d/flappybird/RetroBird/cocos2d/cocos/audio/android/AudioDecoder.cpp: In
constructor 'cocos2d::experimental::AudioDecoder::AudioDecoder(SLEngineItf, cons
t string&, int, int, const FdGetterCallback&)':
D:/coco2d/flappybird/RetroBird/cocos2d/cocos/audio/android/AudioDecoder.cpp:108:
73: error: 'malloc' was not declared in this scope
     _pcmData = (char*) malloc(NB_BUFFERS_IN_QUEUE * BUFFER_SIZE_IN_BYTES);
                                                                         ^
D:/coco2d/flappybird/RetroBird/cocos2d/cocos/audio/android/AudioDecoder.cpp: In
destructor 'virtual cocos2d::experimental::AudioDecoder::~AudioDecoder()':
D:/coco2d/flappybird/RetroBird/cocos2d/cocos/audio/android/AudioDecoder.cpp:126:
18: error: 'free' was not declared in this scope
     free(_pcmData);
                  ^
D:/coco2d/flappybird/RetroBird/cocos2d/cocos/audio/android/AudioDecoder.cpp: In
member function 'bool cocos2d::experimental::AudioDecoder::decodeToPcm()':
D:/coco2d/flappybird/RetroBird/cocos2d/cocos/audio/android/AudioDecoder.cpp:405:
52: error: 'malloc' was not declared in this scope
         keyInfo = (SLMetadataInfo *) malloc(keySize);
                                                    ^
D:/coco2d/flappybird/RetroBird/cocos2d/cocos/audio/android/AudioDecoder.cpp:434:
25: error: 'free' was not declared in this scope
             free(keyInfo);
                         ^
D:/coco2d/flappybird/RetroBird/cocos2d/cocos/audio/android/AudioDecoder.cpp: In
member function 'bool cocos2d::experimental::AudioDecoder::resample()':
D:/coco2d/flappybird/RetroBird/cocos2d/cocos/audio/android/AudioDecoder.cpp:504:
42: error: 'malloc' was not declared in this scope
     void *outputVAddr = malloc(outputSize);
                                          ^
D:/coco2d/flappybird/RetroBird/cocos2d/cocos/audio/android/AudioDecoder.cpp:594:
17: error: 'free' was not declared in this scope
     free(convert);
                 ^
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: audioengine_static <= PcmBufferProvider.cpp
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/audioengine_static/AudioDecoder.o] Error
 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: audioengine_static <= PcmAudioPlayer.cpp
make: Leaving directory `D:/coco2d/flappybird/RetroBird/proj.android-studio/app'

Error running command, return code: 2.
```

Comment: Have you tried to deploy using Android Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Android-ndk-r15` so,

Add the following to your `Android.mk` :

```
APP_DEPRECATED_HEADERS := true
```

Take a look of this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-r15-release/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md)